# Reasoning laziness

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have the following snippet:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import System.Environment
import Data.Word
import qualified Data.List.Stream as S

histogram ::  [Word8] -> V.Vector Int
histogram c = V.accum (+) (V.replicate 256 0) $ S.zip (map fromIntegral c) (S.repeat 1)

mkHistogram file = do
  hist <- (histogram . BL.unpack) `fmap` BL.readFile file
  print hist
```

I see it like this: Nothing is done until printing. When printing the thunks are unwinded by first unpacking, then mapping fromIntegral one Word8 at a time.  Each of these word8's are zipped with 1, again one value at a time. This tuples are then taken by the accumulator function which updates the array, one tuple/Word8 at a time. Then we move to the next thunk and repeat until no more content left.

This would allow for creating histograms in constant memory, but alas this is not happening, but instead it crashes with stack overflow. If I try to profile it, I see it running to the end, but taking memory a lot (300-500 Mb for a 2.5 Mb file). Memory is obtained linearly until the end until it can be released, forming a "nice" triangular graph.

Where did my reasoning go wrong and what steps should I take to make this run in constant memory?

Comment: This might help http://repos.mornfall.net/mdarcs/contrib/darcs-errors.hlint

Comment: You use `fmap`. <$> is much more cool.

Comment: @Hai but requires an additional import and is harder to type. But I agree on the coolness factor :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `Data.Vector` is not strict in its elements.  So although your reasoning is right, when accumulating the histogram your thunks looks like:

```
<1+(1+(1+0)) (1+(1+0)) 0 0 (1+(1+(1+(1+0)))) ... >
```

Rather than

```
<3 2 0 0 4 ...>
```

And only when you print are those sums computed.  I don't see a strict `accum` function in the docs (shame), and there isn't any place to hook in a `seq`.  One way out of this predicament may be to use `Data.Vector.Unboxed` instead, since unboxed types are unlifted aka strict.   Maybe you could request a strict `accum` function with your example as a use case.

Comment: Argh, luqui beat me to it.  By my tests, simply changing to using `Data.Vector.Unboxed` allows this code to run in constant memory.  I was using the Prelude definitions of `zip` and `repeat` instead of `Data.List.Stream`, but I don't think that makes any difference in this case.

Comment: Great, this helped. I was suspecting that it would be because accum (or somewhere near it) wasn't strict, but wasn't sure how to check it.

Comment: @Masse - the stack overflow error your received was a big clue.  Stack overflows commonly result from the construction of a large thunk, e.g. something isn't strict enough, and arithmetic is a common culprit.